# google-container access the ui panel

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following a course where the teacher connects to google container ui panel by accessing `https://ip-of-container/ui` he is then asked for password and username.

In my case what I see is :

```
User "system:anonymous" cannot get  at the cluster scope.: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""
```

This issue on [github says this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44275):

> A better way to access the UI via the API is to run kubectl proxy and
>   access http://localhost:8001/ui

I don't understand what he is trying to say. Is localhost a placeholder for the machine endpoint ip ? How could it connect to my localhost since I have no server running ?

I did run `kubectl proxy` then,

- try to access `http(s)://container-endpoint-ip:8001/ui`
- literally `http://localhost:8001/ui`

None of those work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the command on the website's console. That's why it made no sens to me that it said to connect to `localhost`. Tbh it's ambiguous, I only used the console on the website so far and forgot I could do things directly on my local machine..

Answer (score 0):

Try running `kubectl proxy` and open http://localhost:8001/ui.

Comment: I did just that as said in my question

Comment: No it did not work as I have nothing running on localhost.

Comment: kubectl proxy port forwards the k8s REST API and UI to localhost at port 8001. Can you reach http://localhost:8001? Where are running your k8s cluster?

Comment: My k8 cluster is on google container engine. No, I cannot reach localhost:8001. I've no server running on my local machine. http://localhost:8001 is unreachable.

Comment: The command is to be run on the local machine and not the console on the website.  Now it works

Answer (score 0):

If you're on GKE you can access the UI for it on https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/workload. It has similar features as the OSS UI and you can access it from any machine, not only localhost.